# Sunspot Solr. How search comments from post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I don't know how search comments only from current post. If i use comment like

```
searchable :auto_index => true do
    text :description
end
```

But, i want search from post comments like

```
@search = @post.comments.search
```

And i get all comments from DB, but not only from current post. Why? ((

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify what you want to search. It returned all comments because there are no parameters for searching

see http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot

Comment: It means i can't do it how i did? And i must set param in model?

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
searchable :auto_index => true do
  text :description
  integer :post_id
end
```

and in the controller

```
Comment.search do
  fulltext params[:query]         if params[:query].present?
  with :post_id, params[:post_id] if params[:post_id].present?
end
```